# DB2 NSP SQL error, max time stamp on left join

Tags: sql, db2

Can anyone help me with this?

I have two tables, Table A that has product-id and Order-no as key, and Table B that has Product-Id, Order-no (as key) along with  Update_Timestamp, order status, etc.
; was trying  to get all matching Product-Id and Order-number existing in Table A that
has
a) matching record in table B - with the latest timestamp of order from table B
b) non-matching records in Table B
to get both a) and b) both in the result set as below.

**Product (Table A)**

| Product_id | Order_no |
| --- | --- |
| 1234567 | S12345 |
| 1234568 | S12346 |
| 1234569 | P12347 |
| 1234575 | M12347 |

**Orderdetails (Table B)**

| Product_id | Order_no | Update_ts | Order_stat |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234567 | S12345 | 2020-05-05-05.01.02.123455 | P |
| 1234567 | S12345 | 2020-06-05-05.01.02.123455 | P |
| 1234567 | S12345 | 2020-07-05-05.01.02.123455 | C |
| 1234568 | S12346 | 2021-05-05-06.01.02.123456 | C |
| 1234569 | P12347 | 2021-05-05-06.01.02.000145 | C |
| 1234569 | P12347 | 2021-06-05-06.01.02.000145 | C |
| 1234569 | P12347 | 2021-07-05-06.01.02.000145 | M |
| 1234569 | P12347 | 2021-08-05-06.01.02.000145 | P |
| 1234574 | T12347 | 2021-07-05-06.01.02.000145 | P |

**Result expected**

| Product_id | Order_no | Update_ts | Order_stat |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234569 | P12347 | 2021-08-05-06.01.02.000145 | P |
| 1234575 | M12347 | NULL | NULL |

Query : If Order_stat needs be filtered say with 'P' order-status for product-id, order numbers  existing in both tables with latest stamp if that order status exists with latest time stamp for all matching orders along with unmatched records as above? .

Edit: Tried the below query, but got an error: `AN‬‎ ‪ON‬‎ ‪CLAUSE‬‎ ‪IS‬‎ ‪INVALID‬‎.‪‬‎ ‪SQLCODE‬‎=‪‬‎-‪338‬‎,‪‬‎ ‪SQLSTATE‬‎=‪42972‬‎,‪‬‎ ‪DRIVER‬‎=‪4‬‎.‪24‬‎.‪92`.   This error has been resolved with latest query suggested and would like to any suggestions for above query
Do you have any suggestions on how to get the expected result?

```
 select 
   aa.Product_id 
  ,aa.Order_no
  ,bb.Update_ts
  ,bb.Order_stat
  from
  Product         aa
  Left join
  Orderdetails    bb
  on   aa.product_id       =bb.product_id
  and  aa.order_no         =bb.order_no
  and  bb.update_ts        =(select max(cc.update_ts) from Orderdetails cc  
                                  where cc.product_id  = bb.product_id
                                    and cc.order_no    = bb.order_no
                                    and cc.order_stat  = bb.order_stat)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to the explanation of [SQL0338N](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=messages-sql0250-sql0499#sql0338n):

> **SQL0338N An ON clause associated with a JOIN operator or in a MERGE
> statement is not valid.**
>
> **Explanation**
> An ON clause associated with a
> JOIN operator or in a MERGE statement is not valid for one of the
> following reasons.
>
> - Column references in an ON clause must only reference columns of
>   tables that are in the scope of the ON clause.
> - A function referenced in an ON clause of a full outer join must be deterministic and have no external action.
> - A dereference operation (->) cannot be used.
> - **The ON clause of a MERGE statement cannot include a subquery.**
> - The ON clause of a MERGE statement cannot include a scalar fullselect.
> - The ON clause of a MERGE statement cannot include an inlined SQL function or an inlined SQL method.
>
> The statement cannot be processed.

Use the following instead. The "base query" (without need for pagination) is inside the full query suitable for pagination, if `(Product_id, Order_no)` is a "unique key" of the result set.

```
select Product_id, Order_no, Update_ts, Order_stat
from
(
select 
  a.*
-- Enumeration for pagination  
, row_number () over (order by Product_id, Order_no) as rn_
from
(
-- Base query start
select 
  aa.Product_id 
, aa.Order_no
, bb.Update_ts
, bb.Order_stat
from Product aa
join 
(
  select 
    o.*
  , row_number () over (partition by product_id, order_no order by update_ts desc) as rn_ 
  from Orderdetails o
) bb on bb.product_id = aa.product_id and bb.order_no = aa.order_no 
and bb.order_stat = 'P' and bb.rn_ = 1

  union all

select 
  aa.Product_id 
, aa.Order_no
, NULL AS Update_ts
, NULL AS Order_stat
from Product aa
where not exists 
(
select 1 
from Orderdetails bb 
where bb.product_id = aa.product_id and bb.order_no = aa.order_no
)
-- Base query end
) a
) b
-- Use of the enumeration for pagination
where rn_ between 1 and 2
order by 1, 2
```

The result is:

| PRODUCT_ID | ORDER_NO | UPDATE_TS | ORDER_STAT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234569 | P12347 | 2021-08-05-06.01.02.000145 | P |
| 1234575 | M12347 |  |  |

Comment: Thank you @Mark Barinstein for the details ,its  getting results as expected. Any suggestion if need to get only one specific order_stat say 'P' (if existing as latest order) from above result set  ?                                               
 Product_id Order_no      Update_ts                                Order_stat
 1234567         S12345      2020-05-05-05.01.02.123456 P
 1234569         P12347      2021-07-05-06.01.02.000145 P
 1234575        M12347      NULL                                        NULL

Comment: The requirement `only one specific order_stat say 'P' (if existing as latest order)` contradicts with the row `1234567 S12345 2020-05-05-05.01.02.123456 P` in the result. This row is not the last one for `(product_id, order_no) = (1234567, S12345)` - the latest one is with `order_stat = 'C'`. Moreover, check if 2 first exactly the same rows in `Orderdetails` is a typo or not. If not, then do you want to see both these rows in the output or not?

Comment: from the above query result if need only one specific order to be filtered out (if thats exist for matching product_id, order_no having different order_stat and different time_stamp ) along with no match records is what would like to see as possible. Here is the image uploaded illustrating  [same](https://imgur.com/VwlKWp6)

Comment: Why do we see 3 rows in the output, whereas the product table has 4 rows? And you haven't asnwered the question about duplicate rows.

Comment: for  product_id and order_no matching , need to pick the latest update_ts of provided orderstatus (in this case P). You are right  ,prior one had duplicates that's been removed ,updated image details [here](https://imgur.com/TiOsX2F)

Comment: Don't post images. Edit your own question instead. I've updated the answer. You haven't answered the question on a number of rows returned.

Comment: ,have edited the post with Table A/B and expected results as per your suggestion, do you have a suggestions for the above result set ? . it took a while for me to update as table values editing the post.

Comment: Look at the updated answer.

Comment: updated   ,CAST(NULL AS TIMESTAMP) AS CREA_TS  to your query and it worked. a) is there any alternative solution? b) for above result set if only 50 records were to be retrieved at  a time ,next time next 50 without impacting over all result  set( as two separate result set we are combining using UNION ) can this query be modified to get 50 records at a time with out missing any records from each  result set combined via union?

Comment: As for "pagination" of whatever result set. If you have whatever `select * from ... union all ...`, then you may enumerate each row like here: `select b.* from (select a.*, row_number () over (order by a.col1, a.col2, ...) as rn_ from (select * from ... union all ...) a) b where b.rn_ between X and Y `. You should use some set of columns in the `order by` yielding unique values to have repeatable rows order amount all invocations of this query.

Comment: with outer enumerations query performance is impacted and taking a bit of time, any suggestions to improve query resp time ? otherwise result set is as expected. Does usage of LIMIT helps with pagination/query performance

Comment: It's not clear how LIMIT could help, since you limit the result set by BETWEEN. If you want to improve performance of such a query working essentially with whole tables without filters significantly reducing number of processed rows, then don't do the pagination in the database. Run the base query once and use scrollable cursor at the application level.

Comment: appreciate your time and valuable comments, Good Day.